# Tomcat console output split to multiple files

Tags: tomcat

I have two different projects running on Tomcat 8.5.

Tomcat is logging the console output (`stdout` & `stderr`) of both projects to `logs/catalina.out`.

How to separate this-- so that the console outputs of these two systems are written to two different files.

Note: I'm aware of changing the access-log file for the project in `conf/server.xml` `<Host>` tag. This is not what i'm looking for.

Also note: I'm not looking to send the console output to another file, but splitting it to 2 different files-- 1 for each project.

TIA

//-------------

EDIT

I'm aware of the logging frameworks. but this is what we need for now.

Comment: Try reading this documentation for more reference https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Console

Answer (score 1):

> Idea of "Splitting console output" to multiple files is bad design.

Log isolation per application is what logger is all about.
Try adding logger to your application. Even tomcat works using `Java logger`
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

> Logging features like **log4j** can be customized and easy to implement. You can even set the logging levels like ERROR, DEBUG, WARN etc. which basically acts as a switch.

Try looking into [configure logback in your application](https://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-xml-example/)